# Using WebView in background

Tags: android, redirect, android-asynctask, android-webview, httpurlconnection

I need to open a website (with possible Java-Script redirects) in a background.

I decided to use `WebView` with `visibility` set to `GONE` (I couldn't achieve this using `HTTPUrlConnection` and `DefaultHttpClient()`. It seems not to work always. I think this is because the method creating `WebView` is sometimes finished before the page is actually fully loaded into `WebView` (I believe method loadUrl doesn't stop the execution).

I've also tried placing `WebView` code in `AsyncTask`, but it doesn't work either.

What is the best solution to solve my problem?

Comment: so it does not load?

Comment: It loads, but sometimes it doesn't manage to follow all the redirects (eg. sometimes it follows just 2 redirects instead of 3). I suppose this may be because the whole request is not completed before method finished (after this method there is no refference to WebView so it is garbagecollected)